# On my Mac, under the 'Shared' folder it shows another computer in my house, am I hacked?

Tags: windows, macos, security, network-shares

I didnt' setup any connection to another computer in my house (its a PC), and I just noticed under my 'Shared' folder in the file explorer on my Mac laptop I see the name of the PC.

How could this have shown up when I didn't even try to connect to it before?

Could I possibly be hacked or is this normal it just scanned our internal wireless network?

I havent' setup any kind of network really, just have a wireless modem that other computers share.

Comment: Well, does that PC have any shared folders enabled? Your Mac would of course be able to discover these without needing to establish a full connection before.

Comment: Look into your System prefs - Sharing to see if something on your Mac is accessable for others.

Answer (score 2):

> **Could I possibly be hacked or is this normal it just scanned our internal wireless network?**

It is normal for computers to become aware of other computers that are connected to the same local area network (LAN). Computers using Microsoft operating systems or Microsoft network protocols broadcast network packets that advertise their existence.

> **I havent' setup any kind of network really,**

Actually you have.

> **just have a wireless modem that other computers share.**

That's enough to have created an adhoc LAN.